# SOSL/SOQL Parse String

Tags: apex, soql

In my controller I have a variable called  category which is of the following format: "category1;category2;category3"

I need a SOQL statement which pulls all case note records that have one of the listed category in my category variable.  Each case note can only have a single category (category__c).

So for example my casenote variable might be "housing;financial;health". I'd want to pull all casenotes where category__c is housing or financial or health.  How might I go about this?

Here's what I have so far:

```
casenotelist = [Select ID, Date_of_Service__c, Case_Note__c,Category__c, Case_Number__c, Entered_By_User__r.Full_Name__c,
                        Case_Member__c
                       from RIS_Case_Note__c 
                       Where Case_Number__c =: controller.getId() AND
                        Date_of_Service__c >=: startdate AND
                        Date_of_Service__c <=: enddate AND
                        category__c ???? :Category //need help on this line
                       ORDER BY Date_of_Service__c  ASC];
```

Comment: List<String> categories  = String.split(Category, ';'); // WHERE category__c in :categories

Comment: Did you try with 'includes' ?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to #kurunve for getting me started.  This worked:

```
 categories = category.split(';'); 
        casenotelist = [Select ID, Date_of_Service__c, Case_Note__c,Category__c, Case_Number__c, Entered_By_User__r.Full_Name__c,
                    Case_Member__c
                   from RIS_Case_Note__c 
                   Where Case_Number__c =: controller.getId() AND
                    Date_of_Service__c >=: startdate AND
                    Date_of_Service__c <=: enddate AND
                    category__c in :categories
                    ORDER BY Date_of_Service__c  ASC];
```